# Does Npgsql expose a strongly-typed list of PostgreSQL column types?

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Npgsql provides [a mapping](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) between `System.Net.IPAddress` and Postgres' `inet` column type.

My EF Core configuration contains:

```
builder
  .Property(p => p.IPAddress)
  .HasColumnType("inet")          // I want to avoid this magic string
  .Required();
```

I know I can just leave it out, but I want to be explicit.

Does Npgsql have a constant, enum or type that I can use instead of hardcoding `"inet"`?

(e.g. `NpgsqlColumnTypes.IPAddress` which would equal `"inet"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open an NpgsqlConnection, access its `TypeMapper` and enumerate on `Mappings` on that - this should give you all the PostgreSQL types that Npgsql supports on that particular PostgreSQL.

However, that really shouldn't be necessary. It is standard practice to simply embed type names as strings. They are well-known stable names which never change.

Comment: Yeah I know but in my experience the problem is not that those identifiers will change, but that I or someone who'll maintain my code will blow something up accidentally. So I always try to avoid magic strings, if I can. I'll just make my own set of constants I guess. Thanks for that interesting idea!